# For single variable, being $x^*$ a local minimzer, suppose $|x-x^*|=\epsilon$. Find bounds on $|f(x)-f(x^*)|$ and $|f'(x)-f'(x^*)|$.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Im studying for a test on unconstrained optimization and completing exercises from a book that doesn't give the solution to all of them. This is one of them, I aren't sure if I am going the right way:

For single variable, being $x^*$ a local minimzer, suppose $|x-x^*|=\epsilon$. Find bounds on $|f(x)-f(x^*)|$ and $|f'(x)-f'(x^*)|$ using Taylor Series expansion.

Consider the distance $l=x-x^*$

Applying the 2nd order Taylor series expansion around $x^*=x-l$:

$f(x^*)=f(x-l)=f(x)+f'(x)*(-l)+(1/2)*f''(\xi)*(-l)^2$ for some $\xi\in[x,x-l]$

Rearranging and taking absolute values on both sides:

$|f(x^*)-f(x)|=|f'(x)*(-l)+(1/2)*f''(\xi)*(-l)^2|$

And applying the triangular inequality ($|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$):

$|f(x^*)-f(x)|\le|f'(x)*(-l)|+|(1/2)*f''(\xi)*(-l)^2|$

Until here I am more or less sure im working out right, then is when I say:

Since there is no condition on $\epsilon$, we can make it small enough so that $x\sim x^*$. Therefore, since $x^*$ is a local minimizer, it must meet the first order necessary condition, that is:

$f'(x)\sim f'(x^*)=0$

Concluding then:

$|f(x^*)-f(x)|\le|(1/2)*f''(\xi)*(-l)^2|=(1/2)|f''(\xi)|*\epsilon^2$

The problem is, in order for  $x\sim x^*$ then $\epsilon$ must tend to 0, yielding 0 in the equation above.

I haven't tried to bind the derivative difference yet, until I get sure where are my major flaws. Can someone help me out on where did I mess up or if I went the wrong way?

Thankyou for your help and time to read through.
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

**Of course** the difference between $f(x^*)$ and $f(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ approaches $x^*$.  This happens for any continuous function.  I don't know why you have a problem with that.

The real catch is that you need bounds on $f''$ in the interval $(x^* - \epsilon, x^* + \epsilon)$ in order to get bounds on $|f(x) - f(x^*)|$.  There's no way around this: the Taylor series coefficients at one point can't tell you the whole picture.

Comment: So, how can I try and answer this question, if there is any? Because that is the question the textbook gives...

Comment: I mean, maybe the way I went wasn't the way supposed to go in order to solve such question.. Does someone have a different idea on how to face this?